# Is it possible to get/select Alt Text in powerpoint using the JS API?

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, office-js

As far as I can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=powerpoint-js-1.2#setSelectedDataAsync_data__options__callback_), there is a method exposed to set selected data, however the example in the docs and elsewhere seem to imply that it only receives a base64 image string, which does not contain any info about the alt text.

Is there an API exposed to do CRUD operations over the Alt Text in PowerPoint images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible in the current Office.js API's for PowerPoint, however API's are improving, and you can vote/recommend this on https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/